# Properness of "?__a=1" method

Tags: api, instagram

How good is this practice to use "?__a=1" for collecting posts/users info?
 I mean like https://www.instagram.com/p/BegPkDGljjY/?__a=1
It's not documented at all so ofcource gives me some doubts about it's reliability. But I see posts even from 2016 arguing about how "it's going to be closed any day now". This method is a big shortcut for me as I don't need to use any access tokens and it even works with business accounts. 
Do you use it for production?

Comment: not a good idea for production, you can use it as long as it works, but if it stops, you should be ready for it. the other undocumented api /media endpoint stopped working without any warning few months ago